# How to show $ \int_0^T\int_\Omega \frac{\partial }{\partial t}( \varphi^2 ) \,dx \,dt = \int_0^T \frac{d}{dt} (\int_\Omega \varphi^2 \, dx) \,dt $?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

$\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is a bounded smooth domain.

$Q_T=\Omega\times [0,T]$.

$\mathring C^\infty(Q_T)=\{u\in C^\infty(Q_T) : u \text{ is zero near } \partial\Omega\times[0,T]\}$.

$\mathring W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$ is closure of $\mathring C^\infty(Q_T)$ in $W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$.  $W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$ is Sobolov space, $u\in W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$ means $u_t$ and $u_x$ belong to $L^2(Q_T)$.

For any $\varphi\in \mathring W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$, how to show
$$
\int_0^T\int_\Omega \frac{\partial }{\partial t}( \varphi^2 ) \, dx \, dt = \int_0^T \frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_\Omega \varphi^2 \,dx\right)\, dt  
$$

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance - what is that weird "W" thing?

Comment: Care to explain what does the subscript $2$ of the Sobolov space $W^{1,1}_2$ means?

Comment: @mucciolo  Thanks, it is Sobolov space, about the subscript, I have explain it in question after edit.

Comment: Isn't this just dominated convergence?

Comment: @SC2020  I don't know, could you talk about it detail ? Thanks.

Comment: Write the derivative in terms of limits, i.e., $df/dt = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} 1/h (f(x+h)-f(x))$, and exchange limit and integral with the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: If you're doing this kind of math then some improvements in your understanding of LaTeX should be worthwhile. In the expression $f(x,t)\,dx\,dt$ you need to manually add spaces separating $dx$ and $dt$ from what they're next to, by typing `f(x,t)\,dx\,dt`. A similar thing applies to things like $f(x_i)\,\Delta x_i$ and to the space between the two differentials in the denominator of $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\,\partial y}.$ Also note that I changed $\displaystyle \frac d {dt} ( \int_\Omega \varphi^2 \, dx)$ to $\displaystyle\frac d{dt}\left(\int_\Omega\varphi^2\,dx\right). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will outline the proof but will let you to fill in the details for by the level of the proposition I presume you are able to.

Writing $\psi := \varphi^2$ to simplify notation, the first thing to note is that the outer integrals are equal
$$\int_0^T \left( \int_\Omega \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}\ dx \right) dt = \int_0^T \frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_\Omega \psi\ dx \right)\ dt$$
if and only if the inner integrals are equal almost everywhere with respect to Lebesgue measure
$$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}\ dx = \frac{d}{dt} \int_\Omega \psi\ dx\ \text{ a.e.}$$

That is, you need to show that the "integral with respect to $x$ and the derivative with respect to $t$ commutes". This is done through the Dominated Convergece Theorem on the usual Lebesgue measure space applied to the sequence of functions
$$f_n(x, t) := \frac{\psi\left(x, t + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \psi(x, t)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

For this you should argue that this is indeed a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions in $x$ and also
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$$

Next you argue that since $\psi$ vanishes when close enough to the boundary then also $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$ does, and since $\Omega$ is bounded and connected then $\left| \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right|$ attains its maximum.

Then by the Mean Value Theorem with respect to $t$ you should argue that fixed $t_0 \in [0, T]$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \Omega$ it holds that
$$|f_n(x, t_0)| \leq \max_{\omega \in \Omega} \left| \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}(\omega, t_0) \right|$$
which is constant and therefore Lebesgue-integrable with respect to $x$ on a bounded set. Thus concluding the proof.